# How to add or subtract timezone offset to timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, timezone, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

I am writing a procedure, where I get timezone offset from database and my requirement is to manipulate the local time with the timezone offset to get the UTC time.

For example,

```
If local time is   : 2/3/2013 2:05:53.000000 PM 
timezone offset is : 5:30
Output should be   : 2/3/2013 8:35:53.000000 AM (2/3/2013 2:05:53.000000 PM - 5:30)
```

Can anyone help me with appropriate function for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FROM_TZ](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions068.htm#SQLRF00644) to form a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value
by combining a TIMESTAMP and a TIME ZONE. Next, use [SYS_EXTRACT_UTC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions186.htm#SQLRF06119)
to convert it into UTC Time.

```
SQL> select from_tz(timestamp'2013-02-03 14:05:53','05:30'),
            sys_extract_utc(from_tz(timestamp'2013-02-03 14:05:53','05:30'))
     from dual;

FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP'2013-02-0314:05:53','05:30')    SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP'2013-02-0314:05:53','05:30'))
------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
03-FEB-13 02.05.53.000000000 PM +05:30            03-FEB-13 08.35.53.000000000 AM
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply@Eat A Peach but in the given example it is subracting the timezone offset but in query it is showing it is adding.. bit confused

Comment: Got the resulted output.. Thanks for your answer

Comment: +5.30 means, the time is five and half hours earlier to UTC. So, at 02.05 PM in India(which has +5.30 tz), the time in england(UTC timezone) will be 8.35 AM

Answer (score 3):

With [Datetime Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions007.htm#SQLRF00401) you can do it even more generic:

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2013-02-03 14:05:53', '05:30') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
FROM dual;
```

or

```
SELECT (TIMESTAMP '2013-02-03 14:05:53' AT TIME ZONE '05:30') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
FROM dual;
```